# Now able to get Id property for flex components

Tags: apache-flex, rft

I am not able to get the Id property for flex components in my flex application(swf file) using Test Object Inspector in Rft Tool.

How can i get them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Flex mxml component ids are only used as a hash within the containing parent.  They're only used for referencing objects and are discarded at compile time.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the id's ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I have one flex application(swf file) having some basic flex components. When i use Test Object Inspector to list various properties of any component ,it doesnt give any value in Id property for that component. How can i get id's?

Comment: What's Test Object Inspector?  There is no 'id' property on components.  There is a 'name' property you can use if you want to differentiate between components, but that's it.

Comment: Test Object Inspector(TOI) is a part of RFT Tool to inspect the properties of components.. Id property is present for components(textfield,label) in my flex application.. TOI is not showing id for flex components in my application

Comment: Again, *there is no id property on UIComponents*.  There is a 'fake' property added only to mxml components for relating things together in the same file (for easier development), but if you look at the API, you'll see that none of these components actually have an id property.

Comment: There is Id property present in my flex application for flex components

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `id` property for your flex component then there are a couple of ways to find out the `id` property of your desired control.

Make sure you have embeded your `.swf` file inside an html wrapper(as suggetsed by RFT) and displaying it in an enabled IE browser.

Hover over the component, say a button(and you should see automation name as well as `id` value).

Else you can do a simple script call to get the id of desired component:

```
System.out.println(desired_object().getProperty(".id"));
```